# How can i find out if an a tag somethimes contain a img as anchor

Tags: php, xpath

I have some xpath code that loops html code for an a-tag and retrive href, rel-tags and anchortext. But i cant determen weather the anchortext is an img-tag, and if it is, can i get the alt tag info?

For finding links, and retriving infomation about them.

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();

    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

    $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");   
    for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {

        $href = $hrefs->item($i);
        //$img = $href->evaluate("img");

        $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
        $rel = $href->getAttribute('rel');
        $anchortext=$href->nodeValue;
    }
```

The above works fine, but i cannot figure out how to determen if the anchortext is an image or not, and if it is retrive the alt tag infomation.

Comment: Will it contain _just_ the image, or can it be image and text? I’d say, access the `firstChild` of the node, or loop over its `childNodes` - and if those exist, check their `nodeName`. If it/one of them turns out to be an image, grab the alt attribute content …

Comment: I dom is an random url, im looking for specific urls in the code, and retriving the data. There are all sorts of internal and eksternal links on the page.

Comment: I fail to see how any of that is relevant to what you asked? You wanted a way to figure out if a specific anchor contains an image or not, I gave you a suggestion for that. _“There are all sorts of internal and eksternal links on the page.”_ - and …? Do you want to limit the selection of links by an additional criterion, before you even start looking whether they contain an image, or what is the point of stating this now?

Comment: if sometimes your anchor tags has image tags inside then just add a checking, usually an `if` statement is used

Comment: Sorry, just tried to explain my issue. childNodes and the loop sounds like a charm, just cant seem to get it working

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath as you do to retrieve the links:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML('<html><body><a href="index.php"><img src="img.png">sdqsdsdq</a>');
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body/a");
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {

    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    //$img = $href->evaluate("img");

    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $rel = $href->getAttribute('rel');

    $anchortext=$href->nodeValue;

    // get images
    $nodes = $href->childNodes;
    $contentAnImage = 0;
    $images = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeName == 'img'){
            $contentAnImage = 1;
            // if you want the image src:
            $images[] = $node->getAttribute('src');
        }
    }

}
```